# My website giveing error again and again Decoding failed: Syntax error

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, layout

http://www.shoppingsamrat.com/ it's getting error on Decoding failed: Syntax error again and again. when we remove cash fine on var it's going fine but after cash its getting error.

Comment: which version of PHP you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Disable compilation.

Open includes/config.php and put # at the beginning of the following row:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
```

Or disable module EM_Megamenupro, then open in adminarea System / Tools / Compilation. Press disable. Enable your module and run re-compile

Comment: i updated my  file as per you but still i am getting same error..